# Processing All Files in a Directory

Tags: perl

I'm new here and I need help, I'm not a good programmer but I debrouille more in the development of web pages (Java). malheuereusement I have not been able to find an internship position in this field, but I have found in each other area having no other choice, I can accept that, unfortunately my training master is not a programmer, he is a director of System and it is even I who made him discover some thing in perl. come in on my Problem:
I was able to Implement a perl-script that parses the file-xml, but for that I must go to my editor perl write the names of all my files, unfortunately I have thousands of files, xml, and I ' love that this code has to be able to find all-xml files located in a folder and the following naturement parser without any time I began to write my editor the name of thousands of files. that's my problem.
If I possessed in 4 or 6 files, I have written the names in my editor-perl and I will have received a result in the immediate

I can somehow summarizes thus:

1- (Extracts XML Perl-script) saved in a folder on my PC stuff
2- Perl-script searches the XML files in the folder
3- perl-script processes (parse) the fichiers_xml
4- perl-script returns me the result of parsing a text file

here is the code I paser für implements, it works well

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use File::Find;

my $file1 = shift or die 'No file1';
my @files = @ARGV or die 'No files';

my $FileResult = 'result.csv';
open( my $FhResult, '>', $FileResult )or die ("Unable to open file $FileResult\n$!");
my $twig1= XML::Twig->new(   
        twig_handlers => {   
                'Parameter' => sub {

                        my $attr_name = $_->{'att'}->{'name'} // 'fault';
                        print $FhResult $attr_name . ",";
                },
        },
);

print $FhResult( (split('_', $file1,2))[0] . ',' );
$twig1->parsefile($file1);

for my $file (@files) {
    my $twig2 = XML::Twig->new(
        twig_handlers => {
            'Parameter' => sub {
                my $attr_value = $_->{'att'}->{'value'} // 'fault';
                print $FhResult $attr_value . ",";
            },
        },
    );

    print $FhResult ( split( '_', "\n$file", 2 ) )[0] . ',';

    $twig2->parsefile($file);
}

close $FhResult;
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what your question is?

Comment: sorry Stewart_R i don't speak englisch very well                                     The above code will parse the XML file in my perl-editor I have to enter
C: perl code.pl A.xml B.xml C.xml ...

Unfortunately, I have more than 4000 files, I do not put myself  enter the names of over 4,000 xml files in my Perl editor, this is the reason, I would like some help from to this that the code can alone  work the files in a folder.

Comment: It looks like you just need to replace the first two assignments with `my @files = glob '*.xml'; my $file1 = shift @files;`

Comment: Hi, Borodin , thank you, it works very well

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a way to find all of the XML files in a directory.

Here's one way:

```
 chdir $the_directory_we_want_to_process;
 foreach my $xml_file ( glob('*.xml') ) {
   process_the_file($xml_file);
 }
```

the `glob('*.xml')` function performs a shell pattern match to generate a list of the names of all the files in the current directory ending in '.xml'

Here's another:

```
opendir(DH, $the_directory_we_want_to_process)
while ( $file = readdir(DH) ) {
   next unless /\.xml$/;
   process_the_file($xml_file); 
}
closedir(DH);
```

Comment: Could possibly add `File::Find` as a way of finding all files.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, I do not know if I'm currently not fully insert it in my code